# Django CreateView redirect to UpdateView if already have an object created

Tags: django, django-views

I have tried how to check(using get() function) inside CreateView. so when we try to access CreateView URL, this view will check is there an object has been created. if yes, it will redirect to that object UpdateView URL. but the problem is I don't know how to reverse it.

```
urls.py
app_name = 'product'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', pglist, name='list'),
    url(r'^create/$', pcreate, name='create'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', pdetail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/update/$', pupdate, name='update'),
    url(r'^redire/$', ered, name='redire'),





views.py
CreateView class
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.model.objects.get(user=self.request.user):
            return redirect("product:update", kwargs={'slug': ??? I HAVE NO IDEA HOW TO DOING THIS PART ???slug})
        else:
            return redirect("product:create")
```

if I change the line into ==> return redirect("pages:update"), CreateView URL show

```
NoReverseMatch at /create/
Reverse for 'update' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<slug>[\\w-]+)/update/$']
```

so, what it should be?

```
return redirect("product:update", kwargs={'slug': ??? I HAVE NO IDEA HOW TO DOING THIS PART ???slug})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I would hazard a guess you have a `slug` field on your model, and you could provide the slug to the `reverse` method's kwargs like so:

```
return redirect(
    "product:update", 
    kwargs={'slug': self.model.objects.get(user=self.request.user).slug}
)
```